# Unity Vector3 y and z Components being set 0

Tags: unity, vector, component-based

So I'm working on an RTS game and I'm trying to set pre-defined positions for units using my own formula. It takes the list of units and makes a position for each one in an array. The array then goes through a for loop which offsets each x position so units don't collide. The problem is that the Y and Z components are set to 0 whenever I try to get them to move. I'm not sure why because I'm not touching them.

Here it is:

Selected units list if you needed it

```cs
    public static List<GameObject> SelectedUnits;
```

```cs
    void MakeFormation(RaycastHit hit)
    {
        Vector3 origin = hit.point;
        float Separation = 10f;
        Vector3[] positions = new Vector3[SelectedUnits.Count];

        for(int i = 0; i < positions.Length; i++)
        {
            positions[i].x = origin.x+Separation*i;
        }
        MultiSelect(positions, origin);
    }
```

And the function that actually gets the units going

````cs
    void MultiSelect(Vector3[] positions, Vector3 origin)
    {
        Debug.Log(SelectedUnits);
        if (SelectedUnits.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i= 0; i < positions.Length; i++)
            {
                Debug.Log("Moving group to area: " + positions[i].ToString("F4"));
            }

            for(int i=0; i< SelectedUnits.Count;i++)
            {

                Debug.Log("Index: " + i);
                SelectedUnits[i].GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>().SetDestination(positions[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```
````

Comment: Where do you initialize your y and z coordinates to something other than zero?

Comment: In another part of the code however I have not changed anything there and it works perfectly there as well.

Comment: I just remembered where Ive gone wrong. Im sorry, I forgot to store the y and z components in the array as well. I will update.